# Which type of correlation is used when IV has four categories?

Tags: regression, correlation, categorical-data, instrumental-variables

I am working on parenting styles (IV) that is a categorical variable with 4 categories. My DVs are personality traits and quality of life. I have created dummy variables (IV) for regression analysis. But I am unable to find out the type of correlation that is best suited for my data set.

Comment: How about a logistic regression with one-hot encoding?

Comment: Please tell us more about your data and research goals!